# Как перенаправить запросы nginx на основе ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Всем добрый день. Начальство поставило задачу по установке nginx и перенаправления с ip адреса на имена. Ранее никогда не сталкивался с nginx и входе изучения совсем запутался с построением команд. Нужно установить соединение с имеющимся доменом и собственным сервером (zabbix который уже установлен, но на apache). Сайты, как и nginx стоят на разных машинах. Просьба к добрым людям, помочь с построением конфигурации. Ранее я уже попытался создать конфиг для сайта в разделе "sites-available" и выглядит примерно так:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name testzabbix.ru;
location / {
    proxy_pass 192.168.1.238:8080;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

При такой конфигурации выдает ошибку:
nginx: [emerg] invalod URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testsite.loc:96
Но подробно посмотрев, не увидел там какой-либо ошибки.

Полный конфиг(zabbix):

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/testzabbix.loc;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name testzabbix.loc;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testzabbix.ru;
    location / {
        proxy_pass 192.168.1.238:8080;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: не понятно в чём затруднение. читаете https://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html, делаете server для каждого вашего доменного имени. но если действительно трудности и если стоит апач и если всё настроено то, может, просто донастроить его?

Comment: Затруднение вызвано тем, что при попытке проверить конфигурацию с помощью команды nginx -t выдает ошибку. Явно что-то неправильно в конфиге. Потому и прошу помощи с построением. Более того, это лишь пример одного сайта. А по факту нужно установить соединение с существующим сайтом и zabbix-server. Эти сайты установлены на разные машины, так же как и nginx. В этом и есть вся сложность. Для многих это явно не проблема, но в данном случае новичек.

Comment: покажите полный конфиг testsite.loc. уберите концевой слеш в proxy_pass, `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.100;`

Comment: Поменял на тот чем занимаюсь. Первоначальный вариант поменял, так как был для теста. Сейчас оригинал.

Comment: testzabbix.loc работает? в testzabbix.ru proxy_pass содержит ошибку

Comment: testzabbix.loc не работает. Содержит точно такую же ошибку.
В proxy_pass ведь нужно указывать IP адрес и порт, разве нет? Если нет, то можете более подробно объяснить в чем ошибка?

Comment: не задан протокол. "proxy_pass Задаёт __протокол__ и адрес проксируемого сервера" http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: Понял в чем ошибка, но тут тогда другой вопрос. Обычно входи на web-интерфейс zabbix входит через ip-адрес/zabbix. Может ли такое правописание конфликтовать с протоколом?

Comment: не будет, запрос будет отпроксирован на указанный бэкенд